# WebStorm 11 Invalid descendent file name "http:"

Tags: http, ftp, webstorm

I downloaded the recent update bringing my version to 11.0.3 and now I get this ftp error: Invalid descendent file name "http:". I have managed to connect to my server using FTPS, although it still returns an error as being 'unable to create folder ftps://example.com/app/'

Recap. Cannot connect to ftp server, can connect to ftps, but cannot upload. Was working a charm before the update. Solution? Or way to rollback update?

Windows 8.1

Thanks!

Comment: Double check your deployment settings. If nothing -- delete it; close project; re-open it and create deployment entry again. So far it looks like either misconfiguration (wrong value in wrong field -- most likely, based on your message) .. or you already have a file on remote server that IDE is unable to process

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah, i've been through the settings countless times, deleted them, re-created, restarted pc, disabled firewall. Everything bar uninstalling the ide. I can connect to the server no probs on the integrated terminal, just for irony's sake I presume. A file on the server however, what could that be, anything relating to php://input?

Comment: Fixed it thanks. There was a directory named "http:" it seems obvious now haha.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else gets a similar error, I browsed to my FTP host via Windows Explorer and lo and behold there was a directory named "http:" - Delete that folder and you'd be fine.

I can't believe I've spent an afternoon going round in circles :/

Thanks to @LazyOne for helping me join the dots :)